# Remove specific node from Firebase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I remove this specific node in my database as shown in this picture below? (the nickname will be different since I'm just testing it, if anyone confuses)
[image]

I've tried

```
    const roomRef = firebase.database().ref(`allRooms/${rooms}`);

    roomRef.orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(`${username}`).once('value',(snapshot)=> {  
                   snapshot.ref.remove();  })
```

But it just delete all of my nodes in that room, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. And your code needs to handle the fact that `` is a list with something like:

```
roomRef.orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(username).once('value',(snapshot)=> {
  snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {  
    userSnapshot.ref.remove();  
  })
})
```

---

The above runs a separate `remove()` call for each matching node. If you have only one (or a few) nodes with the same name, this is probably fine. But if you have more of them, consider using a single multi-path update to remove all nodes like this:

```
roomRef.orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(username).once('value',(snapshot)=> {
  let updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {  
    updates[userSnapshot.key] = null; //  setting to null will remove the node
  })
  roomRef.update(updates); //  send all updates in one call
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `snapshot.ref` will be `roomRef` itself therefore using `remove()` method on that will remove whole `allRooms/roomId` node. To delete that specific child node, you need a reference to that. Try this:

```js
const roomRef = firebase.database().ref(`allRooms/${rooms}`);

roomRef.orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(`${username}`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {  
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    const keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
    snapshot.ref.child(keys[0]).remove().then(() => {
      //         ^^^^^ deleting that child instead of roomRef
      console.log("Data Deleted")
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));  
  }
})
```